# How to check if value exist in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

Is there a way to find a specific value inside of existing datatable?
After finding it I want to like put the information of row in a single var for example its like selected then getting the data like this

`$('#datatable').DataTable().rows({selected:true}).data();`

now I want it to work like searching if I input `two` and the datatable has that value on specific column It will give me the true in if else, Then I want it to store that value in a var in javascript.

I also know how to get all the data in datatable. I just don't know how to get the data of a single row using if else. Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

Here's what I want to happen

> The user will input a data > The System will check if that data is
>   existing in datatable > If not existing error will occur > If
>   existing, Store the whole row in var e.g: var data = //the whole row
>   data

Comment: if you have a count() function, you can use it to test if value is 0 (does not exist) or greater than 0 if does exists.

Comment: count on datatable? I know how the count works if its all data. I don't know how can i filter it for a single data.

Comment: `$('#datatable').DataTable().rows({selected:true}).data();` That returns an array doesnt it? Can you iterate over the array and check if the value exists in it?

Comment: I know how that works. The data is not selected the user will only input the data and I want the system to check if the inputted data is existing in datatable

Comment: Then add an event listener `onChange` on your data cells. And check the value there.

Comment: thats what I want to know on how to check if the value is there @VTodorov

Comment: Well in the `onChange` event you get the value that the user inputs and compare it to the array that `$('#datatable').DataTable().rows({selected:true}).data();` returns?

Comment: Like I said the there's no selected data in the table so there's no array that return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`{search: 'applied'}`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier#search) selector-modifier

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable()

console.log(table.search('Tokyo').row({search: 'applied'}).data())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Numero</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>155555</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: does it have the function to only search a specific column?

Comment: `$(...).search is not a function` got this error. I tried this one `alert($('#asset-table').search('Stocked').row({search: 'applied'}).data());`

Comment: Solved it! Thanks A lot!